What are the bonding and grounding requirements for my heavy-up and new panel?
Jurisdiction is Dayton, OH - currently on NEC 2023.
I'm upgrading from a 100A service going through a meter on the outside of my house and into a main service panel inside my house.
The new system will be a 200A service coming to a meter/main outside my house, then going to a subpanel inside the house that will serve as the primary point of distribution for power within the house.  The meter/main outside is primarily for the external disconnect now required, but also to get a bit of flexibility for future shed, solar, etc.
I felt like I had a good grasp of things and was moving forward, at which point we welcomed a baby - so I'm now scrambling to complete part of the project just so it's not in a terrible limbo.  The main change to my plans is that I'm not able to remove the old main panel yet: I'm going to have to continue using it as a sub(sub)panel until I can, one-by-one, move circuits off of it.  (Side note: I know this means I will need to disconnect the bonding jumper and be sure ground and neutral are distinct within this, since it's currently the main panel)
Before I try to get the power switched over to the new service, I want to be sure I've got everything correct - my biggest question right now is related to grounding and bonding (and to be entirely honest, I'm a little hazy on the distinction).  I understand that the neutral will bond with ground exclusively at the main panel.  At that point, I'll also connect the ground to 2 ground rods.
From there, I use 4/0-4/0-4/0-2/0 SER to go to the "main" sub-panel inside my house.  I have some equipment inside my house that I think needs to be grounded, and I this is where my main questions come from.

Black Pipe for Natural Gas: this runs to a couple places (water heater, furnace, and eventually a stove in the kitchen) - since the furnace is grounded, is this bonding/grounding (again, hazy on the distinction) sufficient/acceptable?

Water: My water comes in from a metal pipe that runs underground, then goes to a bunch of PEX for everything else - there's a bit of metal around the water heater (which non-electric, all natural gas and a manual pilot light), and some metal around external spigots.  Do I need to run wire to those and tie them in to ground?  What about where the water enters?

Sewer: I have giant old cast iron stacks (2) in my basement where all the waste water in my house ends up.  Do these need bonding?


Is there any other equipment I might need to worry about?
Assuming I do need to run cables to things, can the ground cables just come back to, say, my "main" sub-panel inside the house - and, since that's grounded properly back to the main panel, we're golden?  Or do I need to tie these back out directly to the ground rods?  What NEC section can I study to guide me, and are there any "gotchas" I need to watch out for when reading?

I wouldn't bother removing the old main unless it's a Zinsco or something. You could hook up all the new hardware alongside the old, lay the wires for the original to become a subpanel, and on cutover day, the new hardware goes live and the old hardware goes dead, and then you change 3 wires in the old main and it's a sub now.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica In the short term that's doable, but eventually we're going to finish the basement and that panel's location would make it impossible to frame a wall in.  I appreciate the suggestion!

The gas will be fine
Since you have black iron gas pipe, the furnace is sufficient bonding for the gas system according to NEC 250.104(B) point 1.  (If you had flexible CSST, you'd need additional bonding, but that's a different can of worms governed by the fuel gas code.  All the electrical grounding and bonding stuff is in NEC Article 250.)
You'll need to bond your water service
Unless the water service was already bonded with 4AWG or heavier copper, you'll need to get some 4AWG bare copper and run it from where the water service line enters to either the new meter-main itself or an existing grounding electrode conductor that is 4AWG or larger, as per NEC 250.104(A), 250.52(A) Point 1, and Table 250.66.  (Note that if you use a direct burial clamp on the water line, you can do this run entirely outdoors if you don't mind digging up where the water line enters the house.)
And bonding the stacks may be wise as well
While bonding metal waste (sewer) piping isn't common, if the lateral those stacks tie into is cast-iron as well, then I would bond a stack, once again using 4AWG copper for this.  This is because a bonded cast-iron sewer lateral serves as an additional grounding electrode for the house as per 250.52(A)(8), in addition to the water service line electrode.

Just a quick question re OP's "I understand that the neutral will bond with ground exclusively at the main panel": wouldn't the new neutral-ground bond need to be at the new external disconnect? All ground leads would actually go back to the external disconnect ground tie? And all inside panels would be considered subpanels with separated neutral and ground?

@Triplefault yeah, the new external disconnect will be his main panel, he's already got that figured out

I think there was some ambiguity between "main panel" (which is actually my meter-main, outdoors, external disconnect) and "primary point of distribution" (which I've called the 'main' panel - actually the first subpanel).
@ThreePhaseEel Thank you for the references, I'll be studying through Article 250 today.  When you say "existing grounding electrode conductor that is 4AWG or larger" I assume that means it CAN go back to the subpanel, since that's grounded through a 2/0 line going back to the main bonding in the meter/main?

@user112697 no, it can't go back to the subpanel because that 2/0 line is an equipment grounding conductor, not a grounding electrode conductor

@ThreePhaseEel Can you clarify the distinction? Does that mean I need to take the 4AWG copper from the water pipe, and (assuming it’s indoors) take it to through the wall penetration where the SER enters the house (or another penetration I guess) and out to where the neutral and ground are bonded in the meter/main, or to one of the ground rods?

@user112697 to the meter-main, since your ground rod wire is likely 6AWG and thus too small to have the water pipe bond branch off it
